# Equinox <-> OSGI version correspondence

Tags: osgi, equinox

I found Knopflerfish <-> OSGI version correspondence table [here](http://www.knopflerfish.org/download.html)

```
KF 4.0.0 <-> OSGi R4 v4.3
KF 3.6.0 <-> OSGi R4 v4.2
KF 2.4.0 <-> OSGi R4 v4.01
KF 1.3.7 <-> OSGi R3
```

I would like to find the same information about [Equinox](http://eclipse.org/equinox/) but can't find it on Equinox web site.

Thanks for helping.

PS: Also pointing out Equinox implementing OSGI 4.2 would be a plus :-)

Comment: This has been answered over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568803/which-version-of-osgi-is-implemented-by-which-version-of-eclipse-equinox

Answer (score 1):

A version of equinox is the OSGi reference implementation for all these releases. So picking the latest version of equinox is up to date, this is currently release 5. This release is backward compatible with 4.2