# Which version of OSGi is implemented by which version of Eclipse/Equinox?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, release, equinox

We are looking for a table which matches Eclipse/Equinox release versions to the corresponding OSGi Service Platform specification release version. 
Eclipse/Equinox wiki doesn't have any info on this in a structured form.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The release archaeology is quite hard. So far we have these versions collected:

```
Year | Eclipse | Release  | OSGi spec | Equinox implementation version  
     | version | name     | version   | org.eclipse.osgi | org.eclipse.osgi.services
-----|---------|----------|-----------|------------------|--------------------------
2004 | 3.0     |          | 4.0 early |                  |                                   
2005 | 3.1     |          | 4.0 draft |                  |                                   
2006 | 3.2     | Callisto | 4.0       |                  |                                   
2007 | 3.3     | Europa   | 4.1       |                  |                                   
2008 | 3.4     | Ganymede | 4.1       | o.e.o_3.4.x      | o.e.o.services_3.1  
2009 | 3.5     | Galileo  | 4.2       | o.e.o_3.5.x      | o.e.o.services_3.2  
2010 | 3.6     | Helios   | 4.2       | o.e.o_3.6.x      | o.e.o.services_3.2  
2011 | 4.1/3.7 | Indigo   | 4.3       | o.e.o_3.7.x      | o.e.o.services_3.3  
2012 | 4.2/3.8 | Juno     | 5         | o.e.o_3.8.2      | o.e.o.services_3.3.100  
2013 | 4.3     | Kepler   | 5         | o.e.o_3.9.x      | o.e.o.services_3.3  
2014 | 4.4     | Luna     | 5         | o.e.o_3.10.x     | o.e.o.services_3.4  
2015 | 4.5     | Mars     | 5         | o.e.o_3.10.102   | o.e.o.services_3.5
2016 | 4.6     | Neon     | 6         | o.e.o_3.11.x     | o.e.o.services_3.5  
2017 | 4.7     | Oxygen   | 6         | o.e.o_3.12.x     | o.e.o.services_3.6
2018 | 4.8     | Photon   | 6         | o.e.o_3.         | o.e.o.services_3.6
2018 | 4.9     | 2018-09  | 6         | o.e.o_3.         | o.e.o.services_?
2018 | 4.10    | 2018-12  | 6         | o.e.o_3.13.200   | o.e.o.services_3.7.0
2019 | 4.11    | 2019-03  | 6         | o.e.o_3.13.300   | o.e.o.services_3.8.0
2019 | 4.12    | 2019-06  | 7         | o.e.o_3.14.0     | o.e.o.services_3.8.0
2019 | 4.13    | 2019-09  | 7         | o.e.o_3.14.x     | o.e.o.services_3.x
2019 | 4.14    | 2019-12  |           |      | 
2020 | 4.15    | 2020-03  |           |      | 
2020 | 4.16    | 2020-06  |           |      | 
2020 | 4.17    | 2020-09  |           |      | 
2020 | 4.18    | 2020-12  |           |      | 
2021 | 4.19    | 2021-03  |           |      | 
2021 | 4.20    | 2021-06  |           |      | 
2021 | 4.21    | 2021-09  |           |      | 
2021 | 4.22    | 2021-12  |           |      | 
2022 | 4.23    | 2022-03  |           |      | 
2022 | 4.24    | 2022-06  |           |      |
```

Comment: Thank you @bj-hargrave for your inputs. Are you sure about the 3.0? Have a look here http://www.eclipse.org/osgi/

Comment: Equinox (which is the OSGi implementation) is 3.9 in Kepler.

Comment: The OSGi R4 spec did not release until Oct 2005. So it is unlikely that the 2004 and 2005 releases of Eclipse could have implemented that final spec. Also, I have been involved in the OSGi spec work since before R1 and the Eclipse OSGi implementation since before 3.0. It was my original OSGi R3 implementation that was contributed to Eclipse for 3.0.